# Is the wave equation a periodic wave equation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves

I have seen that in the derivation of wave equation, they always use the *periodic property* of waves in the derivation. But what about *non-periodic* waves? Do they have some different wave equation?

Is the general wave equation $$\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2}$$
a *periodic* wave equation?

Please help.

**EDIT**: If the question is difficult to understand as what it now stands, I would add that I am looking for non-linear equations with solitons as solutions.

Comment: Linear wave equations, including the one above, can have perfectly non-periodic solutions. I am not sure what you mean. Do you mean that it's homogeneous? Are you looking for non-linear equations with solitons for solutions?

Comment: In fact, no derivation of $\partial_x^2\psi=\partial_{ct}^2\psi$ I've ever seen has used any periodic property of  waves.

Comment: @CuriousOne Yes, that's it.

Comment: You should edit your question to make clear what you are really up to.

Comment: The wave equation that you quote, $\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2}$, is a linear equation.

Answer (score 5):

Solutions to the wave equation need not be periodic.  In fact, any profile with the argument $x \pm c t$ will satisfy the wave equation.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is an equation of a moving function. Take any general function dependent on position and time such that the function is f(x+ct). Now, partially differentiate it by applying chain rule. You will see that you end up with the same differential equation as above.